# joining two table in linq to sql query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Hi all I have the following

```
ComplaintData = 
(from s in context.tbl_Complaints
 join t2 in context.tbl_lk_property_types on s.property_type equals t2.id.ToString()
 where s.id == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"])
 select new { s, t2.text }).ToList();
```

where context.tbl_lk_property_types.id is an int and s.property_type is a string.

I have tried joining them like this

```
on Convert.ToInt32(s.property_type) equals t2.id
```

and this

```
on s.property_type equals t2.id.ToString()
```

but both throw an error. Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: when I do t2.id.ToString() I get Cannot implicitly convert system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.generic.list

Comment: What is the type of ComplaintData? Does it have a specific type or just a "var" is missing before variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework you can use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()` method. You could try something like this:

```
ComplaintData = 
(from s in context.tbl_Complaints
 join t2 in context.tbl_lk_property_types
 on s.property_type equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t2.id).Trim()
 where s.id == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"])
 select new { s, t2.text }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, but in the end I have found it so much easier to just re write it using SQL